# watch network with nightwatch

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to test the frontend of an application.
I'm testing that some buttons are clickable or not.

Is it possible with nightwatch, to know if there was a network
request made by the click, or more generally, to watch the network.

Comment: you could have the button do something nightwatch has a built-in event for, like an element becoming visible, even a clear element...

Comment: this would allow me to test if the button would have change something in the view but what if it doesn't change anything you see, but just get some info not displayed?
furthermore, this doesn't allow me to test if there's no request send when the button is supposed to be disabled.

Comment: you can tie the network action to the detectable event, not just to the click() itself.

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightwatch-xhr in order to watch for Ajax requests from Nightwatch.js.

(I'm one of the maintainers)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible with nightwatch, to know if there was a network request made by the click, or more generally, to watch the network.

No it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with plain nightwatch. It can be done with browsermob which enables to record your browser request and saves in HAR format. You have to integrate browsermob-proxy. I have responded to another similar post. Check this.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nightwatchjs/NFBi0fnQNT8/Dp9t1-CDBQAJ

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to capture the XHR traffic:

https://github.com/Bugazelle/nightwatch-capture-network-traffic

#### How it is working

1. Take advantage of the `ajaxListener.js`

   > The js is forked from https://gist.github.com/icodejs/3183154

   This hack will make all the XHR requests as a warn log to console

```
    {
        "type": "response",
        "syncMode": this.syncMode,
        "method": this.method,
        "url": this.url,
        "requestData": this.requestData,
        "readyState": this.readyState,
        "responseText": this.responseText,
        "responseCode": this.status,
        "responseHeader": this.getAllResponseHeaders()
    }
```

2. Then take advantage of Nightwatch API [.getLog](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getLog.html)

   The [.getLog](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getLog.html) could capture the console warn logs for us