# Monitoring requests and responses with nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch and was hoping to monitor the http requests that are being generated by my nightwatch steps.  Is there a way to listen to the requests that are sent and the responses received.  I dont need to modify them.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Might be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285960/watch-network-with-nightwatch

Comment: @swiss196 no I didn't get anywhere with this. The feedback I got was it is not possible

Comment: Hey, @matt it's been a year and 7 months, has there been any work done on this? e2e automation testing for error pages is what I'm after, so it would be cool to alter a request after a click/submit action to get back the correct error page. :)

Comment: no change as far as I know sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

In order to monitor the HTTP requests:
It's basically will monitor when user click on event that send a
request to the server such as: submit button in login page - that send userName & password.

First install npm i nightwatch-xhr

after that you can make a function like that:

```
module.exports = {
  tags: ["test"],
  "test": function (browser) {
      browser
      .windowMaximize()
      .url("some url")
      .insertValue("namevalue")
      .insertValue("passwordValue")

      //then write something like that
      .waitForXHR(
      "",
      1000,
      function browserTrigger() {
        browser.click("submit button")
      },
      function assertValues(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr)
      }
    );
   }
  }
```

It will catch the request data that send to the server.